# Component group not showing in sidekick (Adobe CQ)

Tags: aem, day-cq

Im using adobe CQ 5 and I have created a bunch of components. 
For all these components I have set `allowedParents` to `*/parsys` and I have defined the `componentGroup` as `xyz`.

My page contains the parsys component. When I enter the parsys design mode, the list of allowed components does not show the component group `xyz`.

Please help!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kindly make sure that your components **jcr:title** is not the same as the component's name. For Eg: if the name of the component is `text`, then the title should at least be `Text` and not text. Change it and then check in the design mode, it will list your component group.

Answer (score 3):

1. Please verify your **Jcr:title** (text) does not match with your component name. A difference needs to be mentioned i.e. if your component name is **Title**, then your `jcr:title` should have **title**. If the component is still not in sidekick after this, then add this too:
2. Add `cq:editConfig` to your component. This will enable you to add your component in sidekick. There is no need to create a dialog.

Answer (score 2):

If your component does not have dialog then child node cq:editConfig enables the component to show in the sidekick. for more please visit http://www.cqtuts.com/cq5/cq5-component.html

Comment: Please put the important part from the link in your answer!