# AEM 6.2 Components not showing up in site builder

Tags: adobe, aem

I have tried these things on our DEV server (works locally):

1. Creating the component using CRXDE lite.
2. Creating the component in a text editor, using the AEM maven plugin to push the content to author.
3. Creating the content package locally and uploading it.
4. Rebooting the server.

I'm stuck. All of the above work locally, but when attempted on another AEM author instance none of them work.

Is there a way to clear and reload the site builders sidekick?

Any help or ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you be more clear on your requirement. the question is confusing. specially the **2.Creating the component in a text editor, using the AEM maven plugin to push the content to author.** what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The requirement is getting a component available for use. The maven plugin i'm using is the one explained in the config: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/developmenttools/how-to-build-aem-projects-using-apache-maven.html

Comment: So are you trying to build a project structure using the maven plugins and archtypes. your question says "**The requirement is getting a component available for use**" bit confusing to me.

Comment: are you having trouble getting your component to show up in the Sidekick? If so, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300235/component-group-not-showing-in-sidekick-adobe-cq